# Making mobs ride other mobs in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of [the latest Minecraft snapshot (13W09A)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/news/756-snapshot-13w09a-ready-for-testing/), it is now possible for mobs to ride other mobs. Is there any way to make mobs ride each other in Minecraft now (i. e. placing a pig on top of a spider, and then placing a skeleton on top of the pig?),

Comment: Likely no way yet. That just says that the code works. There's probably no means for the player to make it happen in-game yet. Though, it does mean that Spider Jockeys may be able to ride minecarts now.

Comment: Now that we can make Wargs there's nothing holding back my LotR total conversion!

Comment: They'll make it possible in game soon. Meanwhile, _uncovery_'s answer is likely the only way.

Comment: Creeper jockey! Incredibly dangerous splodey thingy!

Comment: I think this is more for map makers, as I don't think you'll be able to do it in vanilla.

Comment: You probably need [Sethbling's MCEdit filter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuZnVmcBY1o).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now. You can use the summon command to make Mobs ride other mobs. For example to put a Creeper on top of a Bat:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"}}
```

The more things you stack, the more complex the command becomes. To simplify this I made a summon command generator that lets you stack mobs, but it gives you all the other options too. It's available [here](http://bimbimma.com/mcstacker/).

Answer (score 2):

You can, with McEdit, but not yet in-game. Here is [a video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMXTYN086hY) on how to do something like that.

Comment: -1 This is incorrect, there is a command that lets you summon stacked mobs.

Comment: Yes, since the latest version there is, but not one year ago when I posted my answer.